# Why failed using rpmbuild --rebuild to build RPM of qmail

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, qmail

I am looking  for alternative solution for my company's email system, 
so I download the rpm source file from the site

http://www.qmail.org/rpms/qmail.html
and use rpmbuild --rebuild to make the final rpm according to the instruction in 
http://www.qmail.org/rpms/SRPMS/qmail-1.03-112_README

(the downloaded file is qmail-1.03-112patch_14_15.src.rpm)
command run: rpmbuild --rebuild qmail-1.03-112patch_14_15.src.rpm

but it finally failed after I solved quite many issues , the final error is as follows:
... (message ignored)
    ./install
    cp /tmp/var-qmail_14_15-root/var/qmail/boot/home /tmp/var-qmail_14_15- 
    root/var/qmail/rc
    chmod 755 /tmp/var-qmail_14_15-root/var/qmail/rc
    hostname -f | grep -q '.'
    make: *** [Makefile:22: setup] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jzyYOt (%install)

RPM build errors:
    line 3: buildprereq is deprecated: Buildprereq: shadow-utils
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jzyYOt (%install)

Anybody please advise me how to check or fix the problem?

My platform is Fedora OS in virtual box environment.
(virtual box version: Version 5.0.10 r104061)
VM is 64 bit Linux
Fedora OS is Fedora 27 Server downloaded from :
https://getfedora.org/zh_TW/server/download/server-download-splash?file=https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/27/Server/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-27-1.6.iso

Answer (score 1):

`Buildprereq` have been deprecated for looong time. Now rpmbuild fails. Either replace it manualy with `BuildRequires` or even better contact qmail developers to do that.